# i3 dmenu not working in Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS

Tags: 18.04, i3-wm

I have recently installed i3 but when I login, <kbd>mod</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd> for dmenu and <kbd>mod</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>e</kbd> for logout doesn't work and it won't let me logout! I know these two important shortcuts and I don't know if there are other shortcuts that won't do an action (I can open terminal using shortcuts!).

And in my Ubuntu when I use `sudo apt list --installed | grep i3` it gives me the following result about i3 packages:

```
i3/bionic,now 4.14.1-1 amd64 [installed]
i3-wm/bionic,now 4.14.1-1 amd64 [installed]
i3lock/bionic,now 2.10-1 amd64 [installed]
i3status/bionic,now 2.11-1build1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
```

And also when I do `sudo apt install dmenu` it tells me:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'suckless-tools' instead of 'dmenu'
suckless-tools is already the newest version (43-1).
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you open `./config/i3/config` are the keyboard shortcuts correctly set?

Something like:

```
bindsym $mod+d exec dmenu-run
```

Also ensure `dmenu` is installed correctly by running `dmenu-run` in a terminal.

Your terminal output looks like things should be correct, but worth checking.

Comment: I just checked that but it didn't work but after trying to find logout shortcut, it displayed a shortcut in another language! I deleted the config file and mod+d and mod+shift+d are now working in the right way! Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Adding

```
bindsym $mod+d exec --no-startup-id dmenu_run
```

to `~/.config/i3/config` worked for me.